# Using setTimeout and recursion to see if something is "ready"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a good way to check if some asynchronous call is "ready" or not. I have some function that runs $.ajax, and in the callback function sets a boolean variable in the global scope to true (along with some other stuff). Before the ajax call, that boolean variable is false.

I want another function that retrieves that "other stuff." Since the ajax call is asynchronous, clearly I can't just immediately go retrieving it because it probably won't be there yet. That's where this boolean variable comes in. I'm thinking I can just check if that boolean is true every 100ms, and when it is, THEN go retrieve and return the "other stuff".

Code-wise, it looks something like this:

```
window.FOO = window.FOO || {};

;(function() {
    var isReady = false;
    var stuff;

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            stuff = data;
            isReady = true;
        }
    })

    FOO.getStuff = function() {
        // How to check if it's "ready"?
    };
}

... (somewhere else)...

var stuff = FOO.getStuff();
```

I've tried the following for `FOO.getStuff` to no avail, because (I think) setTimeout is asynchronous:

```
FOO.getStuff = function() {
    if (isReady) {
        return stuff;
    }
    var theStuff;
    setTimeout(function() {
        theStuff = FOO.getStuff();
    }, 100);
    return theStuff;
};
```

Using the console, I can see it doing the right thing... but the first `FOO.getStuff` call returns before the subsequent ones do.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit: To clarify, I want the ajax call to remain asynchronous. I'm perfectly fine with the getStuff() calls being synchronous, because the ajax call will be very fast, and in most cases, getStuff() will be called later (after the used does some things).

Comment: Why do not just you call getStuff in the success callback of the AJAX call?

Comment: getStuff won't always be called with the ajax call. Imagine that it's available outside the code above's scope. The impetus here is storing compiled templates (the "stuff") and having other various javascript functions retrieve the template that's been loaded. The trick is when I attempt to retrieve before it's done loading.

Comment: Are you asking how to make `getStuff` block the caller, essentially checking the variable every tenth of a second, and unblocking when it's set? Because unfortunately, you can't block one part of the script without blocking everything, and thus, preventing the AJAX callback from running.

Comment: There's no way to "sleep" in JavaScript, unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you look into using a [global ajax event handler](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), such as `.ajaxComplete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments I have your answer. To solve async problem we should do async actions.

```
var stuff;
var stuffQueue = [];
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        stuff = data;
        if( stuffQueue.length > 0 ){
           for(var i in stuffQueue){
              var callback = stuffQueue[i];
              callback(stuff);
           }
           stuffQueue = [];
        } 
    }
});

function getStuff(callback){
   //stuff has been loaded?
   if( stuff ){
     callback(stuff);
   }else{
      stuffQueue.push(callback);
   }
}
```

To get stuff invoke:

```
var something = getStuff(function(stuff){
  console.log(stuff);
});
```

This should solve your use case. Let me tell you more info, I have a JavaScript template engine, not yet open source but I have been using in professional projects, and I load all the templates with just one HTTP request, I made that request async:false because it is a dependence of the project.

There are reads that said that async false is evil, I do not believe so, what is evil is to use it wrong. Loading a templates file master, is a good example where async:false could work.

Additional I recommend you to read about promisses:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: I think there is one problem in your code. stuffQueue needs be emptied after this queue is called.

Comment: I actually solved it in a very similar manner to how you have above, using a callback. In my case of templates, instead of retrieving the template function (compiled via Handlebars, if you're curious), I'm renaming the "getStuff" to something like "applyStuff" which is given a callback function of what to do with that stuff. Seems to work just dandy. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

similar idea with Danie Aranda, I'd like to sugget you use custom event.

```
var isReady = true;

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        isReady = false;
    },

    success: function(data) {
        isReady = true;
        $(document).trigger('display-stuff', data);
    }
});

Foo.getStuff = function(data) {
    if (!isReady) {
        $(document).one('display-stuff', Foo.getStuff);
        return;
    }

    // do something
};
```

Comment: getStuff per the name is a "getter" with this code probably the invoker of getStuff does not have a way to "get" stuff.